# Nginx: Redirect a certain file path url to its new path url

Tags: redirect, nginx

We moved the assets to a new container or folder. From `/documents/THE_FILE.pdf` was moved to `/assets/client_files/files/documents/THE_FILE.pdf` noticed the path is now within `/assets/cleint_files/files/` directory.

The problem is, we already have bunch of content that have links to file but using the old path. I just want to make the work simple, since there are like 2,000 instances of these throughout the site. I'm hopeful this could be done using nginx that it will redirect a certain url to its new url when it detected a link like this `http://www.domain.com/documents/THE_FILE.pdf`. As long as the url's first path is `/documents/`, it will be redirected to new path `/assets/client_files/files/documents/`

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Simple rewrite will do, add this to your server block.

```
rewrite ^(/documents/.*)$ /assets/client_files/files$1 permanent;
```

This will throw a 301 redirect ot requests with URI staring with `/documents/` to the new path.

For more information about Nginx rewrite, check the [docs here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)

**UPDATE**

Also you can do this inside a location like this

```
location /documents/ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /assets/client_files/files$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: sorry but i can't use server block, instead just location block. Is there a way to do that using location block?

Comment: Wouldnt you want to use `return 301` to support seo and robots?

Comment: @ZacGrierson A `rewrite` command with option `permanent` does the same work with `return 301`.

Comment: `rewrite ... permanent` or `return 301 ...` is sucky if you want to test something, because the browser remembers this. Use `rewrite ... redirect` or `return 302 ...` instead!